# Homotopy groups of smooth manifolds?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

> For a fixed $d$, is there a relationship between the homotopy groups of smooth $d$-manifolds?

The $d=1$ case is trivial, but I already don't know how to approach $d=3$ (I should have said that the case of $d=2$ is simple as well, since there is only a sphere to consider, but I don't know how to formulate the property of "having the same homotopy groups as $S^2$" in a simpler way).

Note about the discussion on the comments: it's unreasonable to expect an easy *complete* characterization of homotopy groups of $S^2$, even less for other manifolds. But I think one could try some *partial* relations. An interesting relationship would be: for some $d$, the groups $\pi_n$ can be determined from groups $\pi_m$ for $m<N<n$ (this is unlikely to be true though).

Comment: I don't understand, a relationship to what?

Comment: For d=2, every closed orientable manifold is a sphere, disk, annulus, torus, or something hyperbolic -- the sphere is the only one of these which even has nontrivial homotopy groups beyond \pi_1.  (For d >= 3 this should be much harder and I don't know what to tell you.)

Comment: @Richard, a relationship *between* homotopy groups. E.g. *homology groups* must vanish for dimension `>d` -- now I'm looking for something analogous.

Comment: While for $d=2$ there is only the sphere to consider... is that simple?

Comment: @Mariano, that's one of  my points.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the question. As you say in dim 2 only the 2-sphere has non-trivial higher homotopy groups, but as Mariano says understanding the n-th homotopy groups of the 2-sphere is an extremely hard (unsolved?) question. Does anyone know of any relations they must satisfy?

Comment: Go to wikipedia and look up "homotopy groups of spheres", similarly look at what's in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology notes, esp the spectral sequences notes.  There's quite a bit known, in particularly they're algorithmically computable, they're finite, they're abelian.... for more see the references. 

Comment: @Ryan Budney. Sorry, I think you misunderstood what I meant by "relations". Of course higher homotopy groups are abelian. I don't need Wikipedia to find that out. What I was thinking of was more along the lines of "is there some general formula expressing pi_n in terms of all pi_m for m<n?" If it is hard to write down a relation of this sort for the 2-sphere, then it's probably a lost cause in general too. But this point seemed so simple that I assumed I must have misunderstood the question. Hence my comment "I think I'm misunderstanding the question".

Comment: The answer to your question will depend on how complicated a "formula" you allow. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $d=3$ the homotopy groups can be pretty elaborate.  Consider the connect-sum of some lens spaces. The universal cover embeds in $S^3$ as the complement of a cantor set (except for a few degenerate cases where you have $\mathbb RP^3$ summands).  So the homotopy-groups are pretty complicated ($\pi_2$ is finitely generated over $\pi_1$).  You could probably make an argument that this is about the worst thing that can happen for the homotopy-groups of 3-manifolds.

You might want to phrase your question as a question about the Postnikov towers of manifolds.  Eilenberg-Maclane spaces are rarely compact boundaryless manifolds.

edit: I guess another spin on your question could go like this. We know the fundamental groups of compact manifolds are all possible finitely presentable groups provided $n \geq 4$. So is there a sense in which the homotopy-algebras of manifolds can be anything finitely presentable? Say, for example, $\pi_2$. As a module over the group-ring of $\pi_1$, are there any restrictions beyond being finitely generated?  I suppose you could construct a compact $6$-manifold with $\pi_2$ (almost) any finitely-presented thing over any finitely-presented $\pi_1$ pretty much the exact same way $4$-manifolds with any finitely presented $\pi_1$ are constructed. I think if $H_2(\pi_1)$ is non-trivial you might run into problems following the analogous construction, in that $\pi_2$ might strictly contain the $\pi_2$ you're trying to create.

2nd edit: So regarding 3-manifolds I think your question has something of an answer now, right? $\pi_n M$ is $\pi_n$ of the universal cover provided $n > 1$.  The universal cover of a geometric 3-manfold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ or $S^3$. So by climbing up the JSJ and connect sum decomposition of a 3-manifold, the universal cover is diffeomorphic to a punctured $S^3$ -- the number of punctures is either $0$, $1$, $2$ or a Cantor set's worth of punctures.  In the Cantor set case we're giving this complement the compactly generated topology induced from the Cantor set complement's subspace topology.   So among other things, $\pi_2 M$ is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z$, similarly $\pi_3 M$, torsion first appears in $\pi_4 M$. The complement you think of as a directed system of wedges of $S^2$'s so the Hilton-Milnor theorem tells you the homotopy groups.

Comment: But compact boundaryless manifolds are quite often Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, for example any manifold with a non-positively curved Riemannian metric.

Comment: There are some natural K(pi,1) manifolds, but they seem to be a very sparse family among manifolds.  Once you get beyond dimension 3 I'd suspect non-positively curved manifolds are extremely rare.  For example, take a connect sum of n copies of CP^2. Those never have NPC metrics, and yet they represent oriented 4-manifolds up to cobordism.  Are there any good theorems about how NPC metrics relate to cobordism, Stiefel-Whitney and Pontriagin numbers? I would guess NPC manifolds represent a very sparse sub-ring of the oriented cobordism ring. 

Comment: A bit offtopic, but I would like to know why pi_2 of a compact manifold is always finitely generated as module over pi_1? (One knows that this is not true for an arbitrary finite CW-complex.)

Comment: @PaulMeier: It is not true that $\pi_2$ is always finitely generated, see A. Dimca, S. Papadima, A.  Suciu, *Non-finiteness properties of fundamental groups of smooth projective varieties.* J. Reine Angew. Math. 629 (2009), 89–105.

Answer (score 4):

The case for $d=4$ also runs into complications, pretty much like it happens for $d=3$. One can show that the homotopy groups of a simply connected smooth closed oriented four manifold $M$ is completely determined by its second Betti number $b_2$. More precisely, if $b_2=k$ then the homotopy groups of $M$ are given by the homotopy groups of $\sharp^{k-1}S^2\times S^3$. Again, these groups are very hard to compute.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for this fact?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Arapura wrote ["a brief guide to some recent work on fundamental groups of varieties"](http://www.msri.org/publications/books/Book28/files/arapura.ps.gz). [Pridham](http://de.arxiv.org/abs/math/0510245) gave new new restrictions on etale fundamental groups of smooth varieties. Perhaps Sullivan's work relates to the question.